# AWS Cognito - how to confirm user after signing up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am trying to build an app in React Native with AWS Cognito as authenication pool. My user pool is set to use MFA(optional). My app has both phone/OTP based signup/sign and Social logins. When I signup with a phone number, I get the OTP and all my triggers are working.

Problem is when I signup with a email, I don't get the user signed session or `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` always returns `Not authenticated`

My code

```
    const cognitoUser = await Auth.signUp({
      username: user.email //I get the email from Google signin SDK
      password: Date.now().toString() // some random password
    });

    const signedInUser = await.signin(user.email) //This returns user info, but signinSession is null
```

I saw people saying the user record must be confirmed, so I tried both of these and both didn't seem to be working

```
Auth.sendCustomChallengeAnswer(
      cognitoUser,
      1111 // Some random number as my Lambda trigger will be sending OTPs to phone numbers only
 );
```

```
Auth.confirmSignUp(
    cognitoUser,
    1111 
)
```

I also noticed the `authenticationFlowType` is `USER_SRP_AUTH` in this case, I was expecting it to be `CUSTOM_AUTH`

Right now I am stuck with this, not able to get the logged in user info in subsequent app screens.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have it set up such that the sign up email address used in `Auth.signUp` will receive a verification code, then you will be using `Auth.confirmSignUp`.

However note the method signature from the type definition file:
`confirmSignUp(username: string, code: string, options?: ConfirmSignUpOptions)`

The verification code is a string; not a number as you had posted.

Comment: Thank You, let me try that too. Do you have any idea why its `USER_SRP_AUTH ` instead of `CUSTOM_AUTH` ?